# Looping through limit in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am having a table containing details in MySQL. here I am calling this stored procedure function to js file in my project. if I open web app containing messages section display no. of messages from 1 to 15 only and when I click on next the no. of messages are from 16 to 30 likewise.
NOTE: I wish to write a mathematical expression or loop through that limit function in the stored procedure. how should I approach to those concepts?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkFFS.png)

Comment: See about pagination

Comment: the problem here is when we open messages, have to display only up to 15 messages or less. then, click on next have to display messages from 16 to 30 or less. based upon messages presents automatically. what is that concept that loop that limits automatically and then clicks on next have to display another page?

Comment: Pagination *is* the concept

Answer (score 0):

Use prepared statement and provide `x` and `y` to it as parameters.

Example.

```sql
-- create procedure with dynamic SQL
CREATE PROCEDURE select_with_dynamic_limit (xlimit INT, xoffset INT)
BEGIN
    SET @limit := xlimit;
    SET @offset := xoffset;
    SET @sql:='SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY id LIMIT ?, ?';
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @limit, @offset;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

```sql
-- Call procedure specifying needed limit/offset
CALL select_with_dynamic_limit(2,2);
CALL select_with_dynamic_limit(5,10);
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cdd62da3591d83840b2af07c429b8531)

Comment: Does this somehow remember it's last offset? If not, then what's the point?

Comment: @Strawberry *Does this somehow remember it's last offset?* No of course. *If not, then what's the point?* Storing in service table, I think.

Comment: yes, calling that function in the user repository for service js fie. and yes, it should remember that last offset number and again display the messages of 15 or less present in the next page or when we click on next or older messages.

Comment: @AkramJaaveed I think it's better to look for best practices in pagination for your environment.